# How do I uninstall a VPN dialer program when I receive this message?

Tags: windows, uninstall

I'm trying to uninstall a program (VPN Dialer) and I receive this error message-The InstallShield Engine (iKernel.exe) Could Not Be Launched. Access Is Denied

Comment: What operating system? If vista or win7, do you have administrative privileges?

Comment: definitely make sure you're running as an administrator, but I believe Windows (Vista/7 anyway) turns admin mode on whenever an install.exe or uninstall.exe is launched anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I found one possible fix via Microsoft:

> http://support.microsoft.com/kb/295278
>
> 1. At a command prompt, type: `dcomcnfg.exe`. The Distributed COM Configuration Properties dialog box is displayed.
> 2. Click the **Default Security** tab.
> 3. In the **Default Access Permissions** section, click **Edit**.
> 4. Ensure that you have "Allow Access" beside your name.
> 5. If you do not have "Allow Access" next to your name, either modify an existing profile or create a new profile that has the necessary permissions.
> 6. Apply all the changes and attempt to run Setup.

Apparently ikernel.exe is an InstallShield app? They have a possible fix on their site too

> http://consumerdocs.installshield.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=Q108247&sliceId=1 
>   http://consumerdocs.installshield.com/selfservice/viewContent.do?externalId=Q110719&sliceId=1
>
> According to InstallShield, the makers of the setup program, this is usually caused by cancelling the setup program, then starting it again too soon.
>
> Wait a minute or so, then try again. If this doesn't work, try rebooting your computer.
>
> This can also occur when the engine file, `iKernel.exe` is locked up
>   by something. You can get rid of this error by removing the engine files
>   from the Common Files folder. Go to `Program Files/Common Files/InstallShield/Engine`. Delete the whole Engine folder. Try running the setup again.

Answer (score 0):

> The installshield Engine iKernel.exe could not be launched

I suffered from this error for a week. I hope it will help any of you facing this issue.

I was setting up a VPN on a xp virtual machine and I kept getting this error when trying to run an installshield setup. Here is how I fixed it:

- [Download the latest ikernel.exe version](http://support.installshield.com/kb/files/Q108312/ikernelupdate.exe) and save it on your
  Desktop.
- Double-click the downloaded `ikernelupdate.exe` file to install it.